# UTL_SMTP difference between DATA, WRITE_DATA and WRITE_RAW_DATA

Tags: oracle, plsql, smtp

I've researched about the difference in functionality about `UTL_SMTP.DATA`, `UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA` and `UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA` but have not found a clear difference between one to another, only that it seems that `WRITE_DATA` supports messages above 32k and `DATA` below that.

I've used UTL_SMTP.DATA to send emails and I can add headers and multiple lines. But this same functionality is available for WRITE_DATA and WRITE_RAW_DATA.

Can you help explaining the difference between the three?

Comment: What isn't clear from the procedure descriptions [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS71479)?

Comment: that for the three, DATA, WRITE_DATA and WRITE_RAW_DATA says the same "Portion of the text of the message to be sent, including headers, in [RFC822] format"

Comment: Do you see any difference when your data has special characters like üöä?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS71479), it is quite clear:

- `UTL_SMTP.DATA`: Sends the (complete) e-mail body
- `UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA`: Writes a portion (i.e. typically one line) of the e-mail message. Input data type is `VARCHAR2`
- `UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA`: Writes a portion of the e-mail message with RAW data. Input data type is `RAW`

`WRITE_DATA` is used to send text, `WRITE_RAW_DATA` is typically used to send data in attachment.