# How to send PL/SQL SMTP mail with html body including Turkish Characters

Tags: email, plsql, smtp

I am trying to send an email with pl/sql code which has blob attachment and HTML body in it.
Everything is going well but I faced with a problem again.
My HTML Body is looking nice with Turkish Characters but in outlook 2013, these Turkish Characters being '?' in the body of the email.
My mail code is :

```
PROCEDURE send_email_blob_and_mailing (p_to          IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject     IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_html_msg    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_mime IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_blob IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_smtp_host   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port   IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25,
                                       result_key_   IN NUMBER,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_1 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_2 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_3 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_4 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_5 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_6 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_7 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_8 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_9 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_10 IN VARCHAR2)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(150) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
  l_step        PLS_INTEGER  := 57;

  --rapor parametreleri

my_blob BLOB;

BEGIN

  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);



  IF p_html_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_html_msg);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;


  IF p_attach_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime || '; name="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
 -- error_sys.System_General(result_key_);

FOR rec_ IN (SELECT PDF FROM PDF_ARCHIVE P WHERE P.result_key=result_key_)LOOP

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(rec_.pdf) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(rec_.pdf, l_step, i * l_step + 1))) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    END LOOP;

END LOOP;
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

I could not find any solution.

Comment: Did you try charset=iso-8859-9 ?

Comment: HTML charset is this. And now i tried it for procedure above but still "çğıöİş" coming "?"

Comment: I just realized that "ş" is coming "s" , "ü" is coming "u" but "ı" is coming "?"

Comment: @mustafayılmaz i am trying other choices too but there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. 
the answer is;

> your extended characters with tildas and such are 8 bit characters,
>   smtp is a 7bit protocol (like US7ASCII, only 7 bits are used). IF your
>   smtp server supports it, it MIGHT be able to take the 8bit data with
>   the write raw data routine, if not you'll have to base64 encode the
>   data (which uses only 7bit characters)

You can find difference of write_data and write_raw_data in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288342/utl-smtp-difference-between-data-write-data-and-write-raw-data#:~:text=WRITE_DATA%20is%20used%20to%20send,to%20send%20data%20in%20attachment.)

you can use simply

```
utl_raw.cast_to_raw(varchar2);
```

with the

```
utl_smtp.write_raw_data
```

my last code is below:

```
PROCEDURE send_email_blob_and_mailing (p_to          IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject     IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_html_msg    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_mime IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_blob IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_smtp_host   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port   IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25,
                                       result_key_   IN NUMBER,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_1 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_2 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_3 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_4 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_5 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_6 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_7 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_8 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_9 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       PDF_PARAMETER_10 IN VARCHAR2)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(150) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
  l_step        PLS_INTEGER  := 57;


my_blob BLOB;

BEGIN

  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);
  UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8');
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);



  IF p_html_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(l_mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_html_msg));
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;


  IF p_attach_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime || '; name="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
 -- error_sys.System_General(result_key_);

FOR rec_ IN (SELECT PDF FROM PDF_ARCHIVE P WHERE P.result_key=result_key_)LOOP

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(rec_.pdf) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(rec_.pdf, l_step, i * l_step + 1))) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    END LOOP;

END LOOP;
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```